# CSS Keyframe phone vibrate

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to make an effect like a phone vibration. This is what i currently have: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwWwzx

I'm just trying to figure out how to add a break so like vibrate for a second then pause for a second then repeat.

```
<div class="phone"><img src="https://i.imgpile.com/nucPMx.png"></div>


.phone {
  -webkit-animation: vibrate 0.32s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  animation: vibrate 0.32s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

@keyframes vibrate {
  0.50%, 90% {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
 }

0.50%, 80% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
}

30%, 50%, 70% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
}

0.50%, 60% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: I changed up your example so it pauses for a while at the end of each animation loop: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXeXwG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated your code so that it pauses around 20% of the animation. This way, you get to keep both, the pause at the end, and the quick vibration effect ([DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXeXwG)):

```
.phone {
  -webkit-animation: vibrate 2s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  animation: vibrate 2s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}


@keyframes vibrate {
  0%, 2%, 4%, 6%, 8%, 10%, 12%, 14%, 16%, 18% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  1%, 3%, 5%, 7%, 9%, 11%, 13%, 15%, 17%, 19% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two changes applied:
- The duration of the animation set to 2 seconds
- The movement stops at 50% of the keyframes
This way, a pause of 1 second is simulated.

```css
.phone {
  -webkit-animation: vibrate 2s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  animation: vibrate 2s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) infinite;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

@keyframes vibrate {
  0.50%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
  }
  5%, 15%, 25%, 35%, 45% 
  {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-0.5px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0.5px, 0, 0);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="phone"><img src="https://i.imgpile.com/nucPMx.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really nice vibrate keyframe

````
    @keyframes vibrate-crazy {
      0% {
        transform: translate(0);
      }
      10% {
        transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
      }
      20% {
        transform: translate(2px, -2px);
      }
      30% {
        transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
      }
      40% {
        transform: translate(2px, 2px);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
      }
      60% {
        transform: translate(2px, -2px);
      }
      70% {
        transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
      }
      80% {
        transform: translate(-2px, -2px);
      }
      90% {
        transform: translate(2px, -2px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate(0);
      }
    }
    ```
````